# VS2019 Cannot launch .NET Core ASP 2 web site and browse from another computer on the same network

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have been trying to browse a website run under IIS Express VS2019 from another computer on the same network. I see the following error.

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

I found several discussions where people suggested adding bindings and I did try adding so many different bindings in `applicationhost.config` with specific hostname, IP, hostname+ip, wildcards. When I add any binding or modify the existing `localhost` binding VS 2019 start giving me the following error

> Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'

I am running VS2019 as an admin. What else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovered. I do not have admin privileges on my local PC. Our sysadmin had created a shortcut for me which launches VS2019 as an admin. However, the VS was still not run as elevated Admin privileges. Turns out, you need to be an admin, and you must right-click the VS2019 shortcut and choose `Run As Administrator` with a shield and say Yes to the warning. The shortcut wasn't doing none of that. Now my custom IIS Express bindings are picked up from `applicationhost.config` without any issue.